# Basic question of real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Consider the following definitions: Let $\phi: R \rightarrow R$ a $C^1$ function.

*) "$\phi$ satisfies the Palais-Smale compactness condition at the level c, or $(PS)_c$ for short, if every sequence $(u_j)\subset R$ such that
$\phi(u_j) \rightarrow c$  and $\phi'(u_j)\rightarrow0$
 has a convergent subsequence"

**)"$\phi$ satisfies the Cerami condition at the level c, or $(C)_c$ for short, if every sequence suchthat
$\phi(u_j)\rightarrow c$ ,$(1+||u_j||)\phi'(u_j)\rightarrow 0$
 has a convergent subsequence"

I know that if $\varphi $ satisfies  $(*)$ then satisfies (**). But if satisfies  $(* *)$ then satisfies $(*)$ ?

I believe that the conditions are equivalents, but i dont know how to prove this.  Someone can give me a help to prove or give a counter example?

Comment: $(PS)_c$ doesn't seem to invoke $c$. That seems odd.

Comment: you're right . i did a typo. thanks for your coment about my error. sorry for the typo. the error is fixed

Answer (score 1):

Consider for example the Dirichlet problem
$$
\begin{cases}
-\Delta u = \alpha u -g(u) &\text{in $\Omega$}\\
u=0 &\text{on $\partial \Omega$}
\end{cases}
$$
with standard smoothness of $\Omega$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. Assume that $\lim_{|t| \to +\infty} g(t)=0$ and $\lim_{|t| \to +\infty} \int_0^t g(s)\, \mathrm{d}s=\beta\in\mathbb{R}$. In general, the Palais-Smale condition for the Euler functional
$$
I(u)=\frac{1}{2}\int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2\, \mathrm{d}x -\frac{\alpha}{2}\int_\Omega |u|^2 \, \mathrm{d}x + \int_\Omega G(u)\, \mathrm{d}x
$$
(where $G'=g$ and $G(0)=0$) is not satisfied, in general. However the Cerami condition can hold true. You can refer to the paper *Abstract critical point theorems and applications...* by Bartolo, Benci and Fortunato, published in 1983 on Nonlinear Analysis, volume 7, pages 981-1012.